# Error while creating jar file using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

My Java project does not contain any error or file/folder missing, but when I try to create a JAR file using Clean & Build in Netbeans, the following error occurred:

```
C:\Users\kites\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ImageMinerPro\nbproject\build-impl.xml:689: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\Users\kites\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ImageMinerPro\nbproject\build-impl.xml:517: copylibs doesn't support the "indexMetaInf" attribute
```

Comment: Just do then build, NB version ?

Comment: I am using Netbeans version 6.8

Comment: just do clean and build

Comment: I tried the same in another machine which runs NetBeans 7.0.and, jar file creation was successfull.what is the reason.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with another machine or NetBeans 7.0